# How can I exclude auto-generation code when I search text in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I search text in Android Studio, you can see  Image A

I find the search result includes auto-generation code such as `LayoutHomeBindingImpl`

I hope to exclude search result from auto-generation code, how can I do?

**Image A**

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Follow these steps to directly achieve the goal:

**1.** Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to open `Find in Path` window, then go to `Scope` tab:

[image]

**2.** Click on `...` options button:

[image]

**3.** Click on `+` then `Local` to add a new scope:

[image]

**4.** Choose a name for it and press `OK`:

[image]

**5.** In `Pattern` box, put `!file:*/generated//*`, then press `Apply` and `OK`:

[image]

**6.** Now, all generated source codes are excluded in the result of `Find in Path`:

[image]